# Is there any way to get image data from normal <img> tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, cors

When downloading a gif image using `XMLHttpRequest`, I meet with

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

Exception, But when using the image tag

```
<img src="http://an.other.domain/example.gif" />
```

the image could be displayed, so I wonder if there is any way to bypass this CORS problem by loading the image data through the `<img>` tag, other than modifying the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server side?

Comment: Assuming that by image data you mean the pixel values, you can draw the loaded image in `Canvas` and get the pixels from there.

Comment: @11thdimension — No. The cross origin image would taint the canvas and disable the ability to do that.

Comment: @Quentin You're right. It doesn't allow `getImageData` on `CORS` images.

Comment: @Quentin I take that back, it seems to be possible. Please check my answer.

Comment: @11thdimension — Your answer is wrong. You're testing using an image with CORS permissions granted.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, I got excited because without `crossOrigin` attribute that image reported the `canvas tained` error and after that adding it it didn't. As it turns out without adding `crossOrigin` attribute to image browser is will not consider the `CORS` headers at all. So in presence of those headers too it will throw error unless we explicitly specify that image is cross origin by using this attribute. Apparently you can't make enough mistakes at 5 in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

While there are techniques to get image data from an `<img>` element … they also require permission from CORS.

Comment: confident and clear answer!  thank you. I think I have to  make a proxy then.